# weston user with super user permission on Wayland

Tags: permissions, security, configuration, wayland

### TL;DR;

weston initializes as weston user, without super user permissions.

However the application needs some su permissions and share some files with the root user.

What is the correct way to implement a secure Wayland environment, with weston user having access to the GUI executables?

### Problem description

The backend needs access to some functionalities that the root user have access or that a normal user shouldn't change, such as creation of NETLINK sockets, semaphores, threads handling and shared memory (`/dev/shm`).

However, the GUI apps should access some resources that were created with the root user, such as shared memories, shared files, semaphores and threads.

### Solutions

#### Run as root

We can run everything as root user, but it is insecure.

Just changing the `/etc/init.d/weston` file from `WESTON_USER=weston` to `WESTON_USER=root`

However, [this mail discussion](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2013-January/006871.html) says:

> Weston will create the socket with permissions so that only the user
> weston runs as can access it.  This is deliberate and how the
> authentication works.  As such, you can't run weston as root and then
> connect to it as a different, regular user.  In fact, **you shouldn't
> run weston (including all of GL, shader compiler, protocol handling
> etc) as root**.  I'm not familiar with the requirements of the rpi
> backend, that is, what kind of access is required to run weston, but
> if there's a graphics device that you need to be root to open, we
> should do that in weston-launch, similar to how we handle the
> limitations of linux drm and input devices.

So we shouldn't use the root user and should implement on `weston-launch`. How do weston-launch works? I think the newer weston doesn't use `weston-launch`

#### Group Permission

A group should be created to handle those shared resources? And some private resources to another group? What if the shared resource should only be changed from the backend side?

We can change the [weston-init.bb](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta/recipes-graphics/wayland/weston-init.bb) file to include a group

#### Capabilities

> For the purpose of performing permission checks, traditional UNIX
> implementations distinguish two categories of processes:
> privileged processes (whose effective user ID is 0, referred to
> as superuser or root), and unprivileged processes (whose
> effective UID is nonzero).  Privileged processes bypass all
> kernel permission checks, while unprivileged processes are
> subject to full permission checking based on the process's
> credentials (usually: effective UID, effective GID, and
> supplementary group list).

Should [capabilities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) be used?

#### Other Solutions

What other solution? Which is the most feasible way to implement it on a secure environment?